# Do I need to worry about Concurrent Modification in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, socket.io

I'm writing a small chat application with Node.js and Socket.io.  I have an object, `connections`, that keeps references to all of the live connections, e.g. (pseudocode):

```
var connections = {};
...
io.on("connection", function(socket)){
  connections[socket.id] = socket;       // (1)

  socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    delete connections[socket.id];       // (2)
  });
}
```

Now in another part of the code I iterate over the connections object, e.g.:

```
for (var i=0; i<connections.length; i++) {
  // do something with connections[i]    // (3)
}
```

Question: Is there a risk that the socket's `disconnect` event will delete an item `(2)` from the `connections` object while the loop is running `(3)` and throw an error?  If so, what's the best practice?

I can "mark it" to be deleted and only remove it after the loop completes, but is it necessary?  Thanks!

Comment: No, JavaScript is singlethreaded. When the loop is running, no other code can be running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need, node runs your code single-threaded. As long as the operations you perform while iterating are synchronous, the socket.io callbacks will not get interleaved.

Answer (score 3):

There is no risk.

The JS process is single threaded and will not trigger the callback until your loop is complete.